# Larynx anatomy and effect of configuration of larynx on F2 of vowels

Tags: phonetics

In the bottom-left quadrant of the image below, an antinode ("A") is shown for F2 at a certain point in the larynx. I think the structure just below and to the left of it is the epiglottis and the v-shaped structure above is the uvula, but is there a name for the area of the larynx at the level of the A itself, and to what extent is it possible to constrict or expand this area?

[image]

Image adapted by Sidney Wood from Chiba, T., and Kajiyama, M., 1941, The Vowel, its Nature and Structure, Tokyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the pharynx (cf the diagram below, from Wikimedia, [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Illu01_head_neck.jpg)). It is constricted in pharyngeal (or pharyngealised) consonants and occasionally pharyngealised vowels.

[image]

Pharyngeal stops and trills are apparently attested, although these may in fact be epiglottal instead. Pharyngeal involvement seems more common as a secondary articulation than a primary one (i.e. pharyngealised consonants are more common than pharyngeal consonants). Such secondary articulation is common in Arabic, Amazigh languages, as well as both Northwest & Northeast Caucasian languages.

Comment: I see. Seems obvious now but I hadn't realized the dotted line represented the tongue. So the front wall of the pharynx is formed by the back of the tongue and the diagram is saying that the reason why moving the tongue forward increases F2 is not that the point of narrowest constriction moves forward but that it widens the pharynx (and presumably also narrows the area around the N in the middle of the roof of the mouth).